# Adding .svc file missing

Tags: wcf

I need to add a .svc file to WCF Service Library I have added to a solution (This doesn't have the .svc file). If I specify this file through ad new item (eg test.svc), this is an installer file not the WCF file.

How can I add this file to my project?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot add a .svc file to a WCF service library - you need to add the WCF service file to a ASP.NET web site or ASP.NET web application in your solution.

In a web application or web site, you can right click on the project, choose "Add New Item", and then pick "WCF Service" from the dialog. This will add the necessary .svc file to your web site or web app.

The svc file must to be in a web app/web site as a container - it cannot reside in a WCF service library.

Marc

Comment: I can't see why this is true. An .svc file is just a text file with the .svc extension. It never gets compiled, but is rather interpreted by IIS. You can put an .svc file together with a WCF binary and it will work if IIS is configured correctly. It doesn't matter what sort of Visual Studio project it is.

Comment: @Mark Seemann: as you say "it gets interpreted by IIS" - so you nee the IIS infrastructure for this to work - which is really only the case in web apps and web sites as VS.NET project types, no?

Comment: Yes and no. I normally create a completely standard Windows Library (.dll) project and write my WCF services like that, then add the .svc file by hand if I need to host the service in IIS. The Visual Studio project type doesn't matter at run-time.

Comment: @Mark Seemann: sure - you can do it manually - no biggie. But since the svc file does require the IIS infrastructure, I guess it makes sense that it's available from the "Add New Item" context menu only in web site / web app projects

Comment: One thing to add: if you are doing a VS.NET 2008 project, after going through the steps marc_s outlined, and go to "Add -> New Item", it is not called a 'WCF Service File', but rather you pick "Add-> New Item" and select: **ADO.NET Data Service** from the 'Web' category on the left.

Comment: @atconway: that would be the file needed for a **WCF Data Service** - and **not** for a regular WCF service...

Comment: Yes, you are not allowed to add .svc file if it's not a web/wcf application. The WCF class library is supposed to be used when you have a multi-layer WCF tier so you need to keep separated implementations and contracts. In fact, a WCF class library is a class library with a reference to System.ServiceModel, nothing else.

Answer (score -3):

Just right click on sub folders and select "convert to Application"

Comment: This is not what the OP needs. The accepted answer already answers the question.